# Scheduling a task on iOS

Tags: ios, ios-background-mode

In my application I would like to schedule a task that will occur daily regardless of the app's state - meaning that I want this task to perform even if the app is in terminated state.

I'm aware that I can send `push notification` at the desired time to perform the task, but I don't want to implement the server side solution unless there're no other options.

When looking at `Background Fetch` I see that the system doesn't let me schedule the time of the task meaning it it could occur whenever the system decides it's the best time.

When looking at `Background Task` I see that that the tasks will executed only when the app is still in the `background` and not `terminated`. If the app goes to the `terminated` state then all the tasks are stopped.

My question is - is it possible to schedule a task that will run daily and indefinitely (or as much close to it as possible) regardless the app state?

Comment: You don't need any server implementations to use `push notification`, just schedule it locally.

Comment: @Itachi will it also work even if the app is not running?

Comment: Why do you think you need the app to connect to the server at a specific time?  If it needs to update data, It can use background refresh as well as updating when the app is opened. if you need to inform the user about some change or event then you can send a push notification at the relevant time. If the app isn't running then that probably means the user isn't using it regularly so why would they want it to consume their battery and network?

Comment: The reason behind it was that, that the app would ping the server indicating that's still installed on the user's device. Instead of the server sending a notification to all users.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm aware that I can send push notification at the desired time to perform the task, but I don't want to implement the server side solution unless there're no other options.

If a push notification would work for what you want to do, a [local notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app) should be just as good, without the need for a server.

> When looking at Background Task I see that that the tasks will executed only when the app is still in the background and not terminated. If the app goes to the terminated state then all the tasks are stopped.

As a user, I don't love the idea of an app that I've killed somehow continuing to run. What's the need for that? Most of the time when people ask about periodic tasks, it's because they want to receive or send data for some reason. Do you really want your users to have to delete your app in order to stop it from connecting?

Comment: I see that point from the user side. However, I also need to ping the server once or twice a day. So I was thinking that the Background Task would be the solution.

Comment: @Keselme "from the user side" is why Apple doesn't provide this option for apps.

Comment: A local notification won't schedule any execution.  It will just show a notification at the scheduled time.